# p:splitButton menuitem with immediate="true" always removes last row of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, liferay-6, split-button

p:splitButton menuitem for delete functionality with immediate="true" always removes last row of data table even when middle row is deleted it always delete last row. How is this caused and how can I solve it?
The below data table is inside p:wizard and I have to validate data table field values on pressing next button of p:wizard only.

```
<p:dataTable id="nomineeEducation" var="education" value="#{nominee.prospective.schoolHistoryToSave}" rowIndexVar="status"
        rendered="#{fn:length(nominee.prospective.schoolHistoryToSave) > 0}">
        <p:column headerText="School" width="250">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{education.lookupSchoolId}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Education# #{status+1}: Please select School.">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--School--" itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.schoolList}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Degree Obtained" width="250">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{education.schoolAffiliations[0].educationId}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Education# #{status+1}: Please select Degree Obtained.">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Degree--" itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.educationList}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Dates Attended" width="150">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{education.underGradMonth}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Education# #{status+1}: Please select Degree Month.">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Month--" itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.monthList}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{education.underGradYear}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Education# #{status+1}: Please select Degree Year.">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Year--" itemValue="#{null}" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemList.yearList}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>         
        <p:column headerText="Action" width="150">
            <p:splitButton value="Select">
                <p:menuitem value="Delete" action="#{nominee.deleteEducation(education, false)}" update="nomineeEducation" icon="ui-icon-close"  immediate="true"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Add New" action="#{nominee.addEducation(false)}" update="nomineeEducation" icon="ui-icon-plus" 
                    rendered="#{fn:length(nominee.prospective.schoolHistoryToSave) eq (status+1)}" />
            </p:splitButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said on http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38506, you cannot send data to backing bean if you use `immediate="true"`.

A workaround would be to change your `splitButton` code for something like:

```
 <p:splitButton value="Select">
   <p:menuitem value="Delete" 
               action="#{nominee.deleteEducation(education, false)}" 
               update="nomineeEducation" 
               icon="ui-icon-close"  
               process="@this"
               global="false"
               />
   <p:menuitem value="Add New" 
               action="#{nominee.addEducation(false)}" 
               update="nomineeEducation" 
               icon="ui-icon-plus" 
               rendered="#{fn:length(nominee.prospective.schoolHistoryToSave) eq (status+1)}" 
               />
 </p:splitButton>
```